# How do I disable logging for a rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I have a rake task that gets run as a cron job once a day. It performs some maintenance on a model that currently has 57k+ records in it. This adds hundreds of thousands of lines to the log each time the task is run for whichever environment it's currently in. (Currently it's just in development.)

How can I disable logging for a specific rake task or group of tasks, but leave logging alone for the rest of the app and leave it alone for the model/methods that are called from the task?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The Rails logger is an `ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger` object, but can be re-assigned to any other kind of `Logger` object (or any object that responds to the `Logger` methods) that you wish, including something like this:

```
dev_null = Logger.new("/dev/null")
Rails.logger = dev_null
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = dev_null
```

Put these lines at the top of your Rake task and all logging output will be inexpensively sent to `/dev/null`, which is best explained by its [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/null) article.

Comment: Even with that line as the first line in each of the tasks, Rails adds a line to the log for every record it loads, e.g.

 Photo Load (34.0ms)  SELECT image_id FROM `photos` WHERE (`photos`.album_id = 16616519)

Comment: @Preacher: here I was thinking that Rails would be smart enough to provide one location to set the logger instance for the whole application. Silly me. Updated the answer with a better solution.

Comment: This worked. Is there any chance you could explain what this is doing?

Comment: @Preacher: I think the question clearly explains what it is doing now. /dev/null is a location which can be written to but it doesn't actually write it anywhere, the data is discarded.

Comment: Using "/dev/null" is inefficient (still formatting and writing to a file). `Logger.new(nil)` works fine.

Comment: agreed with @ioquatix, but in case a file is needed, much better to use platform agnostic `IO::NULL`

Answer (score 4):

You can add this to the top of the task:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = 2
```

Comment: FYI: silence is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 4.0

Answer (score 3):

If you have a cron job, you can redirect output to /dev/null like :

```
* * * * * rake whatever_task_blah_blah > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: I'm getting the same result as the other answer.

Comment: This would only pipe the OUTPUT to /dev/null, not the logger output.

Comment: Agreed. He doesn't mention what he actually wants to pipe though. That is why cron can be possibility.

Answer (score 0):

another possibility would be to have a config that is checking for an env var

```rb
# production.rb

Rails.application.configure do
  #...
  config.log_level = ENV["RAILS_LOG_LEVEL"].presence || :debug # default level

end
```

Then you can run anything prefixing the level you want

```sh
$> RAILS_LOG_LEVEL=info bin/rake my:rake:task
```